# Improve performance of AJAX with .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So basically that's the situation:

I have an infinity loop that calls an AJAX request ( POST ) that pulls the most updated data every 5 seconds! and what it does, it calls the Controller to get its data as JSON, looks like that:

```
    public string Reload(int id)
    {
        Room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Room);
    }
```

the thing is, the Line:

```
Room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
```

costs a lot, every 5 seconds it does the same query over and over again...

Is there a way for the controller to "remember" the user so he won't have to do the same query again and again?

**NOTE:** I'm using: ASP.NET MVC Web Application (.NET Framework ) 4.6.1 with Identity.

Comment: Please explain the line `so he won't have to do the same query again and again?`

Comment: @JamshaidKamran to keep alive the variable Room even after the request is done, so the next time the user will active the Reload method, he could get in O(1) the Room variable instead of getting it from the Database,

Comment: Okay, Why not pass it through the params again? like `public string Reload(int id, Room room)`

Comment: Firstly Marvell has a lot to answer for with `infinity loop` i cringe every time i hear it.. Secondly use a protocol or technology/framework that can call back tot he client. like signalr

Comment: @JamshaidKamran it's not secured since the params are coming from Javascript, so someone could just change the Room room to anything he wishes.

Comment: @TheGeneral Ohh well I'll try read about signalr

Comment: `costs a lot, every 5 seconds it does the same query over and over again...` I'd suggest reading up on `MemoryCache`.

Comment: If you want to "remember" the user so that you save the look up, what is the point of continuously looping to provide fresh data?

Comment: @JonP Building kind of a live chat, using SignalR is might be a good solution.

Comment: @Dorki Well, if you're building a live chat, I would suggest fast-forwarding through development and research costs and try bootstrapping your project with Slack instead :) It's plenty developer-friendly (i.e. webhooks, integrations with Zapier, etc.) and even free to start out. And no [disclaimer], I don't work for them either.

Answer (score 0):

A few options for you:

- Using Service Workers (client-side), the client can cache the data for you automatically, but you have to set it up and be careful to expire it with the session, etc.
- Using `HttpRuntime.Cache`, you can build out your own in-memory caching solution server-side if you're not ready to build out a Redis or Couchbase cluster at this time.
- As you are accepting an `id` parameter that changes the results, you may also consider enabling and configuring [Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) for automatically caching it per URL
- If you're using jQuery, also look into the `$.ajaxSetup` **cache** parameter.

My pick would be Output Caching varied by parameter for a set duration so I only incur load, say, once an hour perhaps?